# LLVM doesn't generate CFG

Tags: clang, llvm

I have the program `foo.c` that I compile with `clang -c -emit-llvm foo.c -o foo.bc`. It return a `foo.bc`.
So, I run `opt -dot-cfg foo.bc` for obtain a `.dot` CFG. But, I receive a warning:

*WARNING: You're attempting to print out a bitcode file.
This is inadvisable as it may cause display problems. If
you REALLY want to taste LLVM bitcode first-hand, you
can force output with the `-f` option.*

If I use `-f`, I get an unreadable file.

Comment: what viewer are you using to read the dot file ??

Comment: I am using GraphViz, but the dot file was not generated...

Comment: Have you tried piping the output to a file and then opening that file with graphviz??

Comment: Yes! I get the `Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '2R' in line 1 of cfg.main.dot splits into two tokens`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

1. The *WARNING* is about the bitcode output of `opt`, which is not related to the dot output. You can use `-disable-output` to disable bitcode output or use `-S` to generate human-readable `.ll` file to suppress the warning.
2. `clang` sets optimization level to `-O0` by default, therefore each function is attached with the `optnone` [attribute](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#function-attributes), preventing most optimization passes from operating the function.
3. `opt` enables the new Pass Manager ([explanation here, a little outdated though](https://blog.llvm.org/posts/2021-03-26-the-new-pass-manager/)) recently, and **optional passes** (IIUC, those doesn't impact functionality) will be automatically skipped if the target function has `optnone`.
4. `-dot-cfg` is an optional pass.

So your function has `optnone` attrubite because it was compiled under `-O0`, and the `CFGPrinter` skips it, so you don't get any dot file output.

Your have several choices:

1. Disable `optnone` attribute generation under `-O0`:

```
clang -S -emit-llvm foo.c -o foo.ll -disable-O0-optnone
```

2. Remove `optnone` attributes in `foo.ll` manually, and save it.
3. Switch back to the legacy Pass Manager when using `opt`:

```
opt -dot-cfg foo.ll -disable-output -enable-new-pm=0
```

Note: The legacy Pass Manager does respect the `optnone` attribute, but it is done by explicitly adding a `skipFunction()` in the passes that really want to do so. `CFGPrinter` doesn't handle `optnone` so in legacy pass manager pipeline, the dot file can be dumped as expected.

BTW, the dot output will be directly written to a file whose name starts with a `.` (if you don't specify the `-cfg-dot-filename-prefix` argument for `opt`). Try `ls -a`!

See [this](https://llvm.org/doxygen/CFGPrinter_8cpp_source.html#l00058) for `opt` implementation details:

```cpp
static void writeCFGToDotFile(Function &F, BlockFrequencyInfo *BFI,
                              BranchProbabilityInfo *BPI, uint64_t MaxFreq,
                              bool CFGOnly = false) {
  std::string Filename =
      (CFGDotFilenamePrefix + "." + F.getName() + ".dot").str();
  errs() << "Writing '" << Filename << "'...";

  std::error_code EC;
  raw_fd_ostream File(Filename, EC, sys::fs::OF_Text);

  DOTFuncInfo CFGInfo(&F, BFI, BPI, MaxFreq);
  CFGInfo.setHeatColors(ShowHeatColors);
  CFGInfo.setEdgeWeights(ShowEdgeWeight);
  CFGInfo.setRawEdgeWeights(UseRawEdgeWeight);

  if (!EC)
    WriteGraph(File, &CFGInfo, CFGOnly);
  else
    errs() << "  error opening file for writing!";
  errs() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Following these steps, I got `main.bc` (or `main.ll`, depending on the build). The _Warning_ is really gone. However, `ls -a` returns me `./` and `../`, in addition to `main.c` and `main.bc` (or `.ll`). There is no `.main.dot` or similar file.

Comment: @Evaldo Could you kindly post your `foo.c`?

Comment: Yea! My `foo.c` (mistakenly called `main.c` previously) is:

```#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    int i;
    int n = 10;
    int arr[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Nuullll! You solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

fix for Nuullll's answer

```
clang -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone -S -emit-llvm foo.c -o foo.ll
```

you need to add `-Xclang` before `-disable-O0-optnone`