# It is possible to generate CFG + Callgraph in one file?

Tags: c++, llvm, control-flow-graph

### The Requirement:

I want a CFG + Callgraph per-module like:

https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-dev-guide/blob/master/src/mir/mir_cfg.svg

---

### What Have I Tried?

I discovered that `opt` could generate a Callgraph and a CFG from LLVM-IR using two `-dot-cfg` and `-dot-callgraph` command-line options. But there is a problem: `-dot-cfg` and `-dot-callgraph` are two separate options that don't care about each other. Consider the following C++ code:

```cpp
int main() { [] {} (); }
```

When I try to generate a CFG + Callgraph using those two options:

```bash
$ clang++ -S -emit-llvm Main.C
$ opt -enable-new-pm=0 -dot-cfg -dot-callgraph Main.ll
Writing '.main.dot'...
Writing '._ZZ4mainENK3$_0clEv.dot'...
Writing 'Main.ll.callgraph.dot'...
```

<sub>The reason that I used `-enable-new-pm=0`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67578423/9248466</sub>

It will generate three separate files: one for the calls graph and others for the CFG(one file per function).

---

### Possible Solution:

One possible solution(and my last bullet) is to merge the files manually.

---

#### Environment:

- **LLVM Toolchain Version**:

  - **Clang**: 16.0.0-++20220814102906+6afcc4a459ea-1~exp1~20220814222919.677
  - **Opt**: 16.0.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, westmere)
- **OS**: Debian 10 buster, x86_64 Linux 4.19.0-21-amd64
- **GraphVIZ**: 2.40.1-6+deb10u1

  - **dot**: graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)